# Add typescript variable to browser global context

Tags: debugging, typescript, browser

How do you push a variable from typescript to the browsers global context so that you can debug it with the console?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window) object for this:

```
(window as any).myvariable = "somevalue";
```

And access it in console:

```
window.myvariable
```

Although use this technique only for debugging purposes, as it defies the whole module concept.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

The same rules apply with TypeScript as JavaScript, TypeScript simply extends JavaScript.

So to answer your question on how to set a global variable, the answer is the exact same way you would in JavaScript.

Executing the following code (assuming not scoped) would create a global variable:

```
var x = 10;
```

Note: For this example to work you would need to compile your TypeScript with `--module "none"` which will compile to non-modular JavaScript.

Comment: I'm using modular JavaScript. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Sure, simply pass the global context into your module. Not sure which module pattern you have adopted but something like this should work: `;(function(glbl) {  console.log(glbl);  }(this));`.